# Combining two sequences of keystrokes using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to send a sequence of keystrokes using just one key to accomplish certain task in sublime text 2 using autohotkey. To set a mark in sublime text 2 the key sequence is Ctrl+K followed by Ctrl+Space. I tried

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
Numpad0::Send ^k sleep 5, Send ^+Space
#IfWinActive
```

which will activate the first part of the sequence but has the side effect of also typing send sleep 5, Send and trying to save the file which I am not trying to do.

If I remove the (sleep 5, Send ^+Space) I then have to push Ctrl+Space to finish off the sequence in order to set the mark. What do I need to add after the Ctrl+K to accomplish the ability to set a mark in sublime text with autohotkey?

Answer (score 2):

When Send is used, it will try to send the rest of the line.  That would be why the rest is being typed.  However, I tried splitting them up, and it still did not function correctly.

The following works for me, give it a try:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
    Numpad0::Send, {CTRLDOWN}k{CTRLUP}{CTRLDOWN}{SPACE}{CTRLUP}
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside #IfWinActive, you can use multiple lines this way.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
Numpad0::
    Send, ^k ; Send Ctrl k
    Sleep, 5 ; Wait 5 ms (probably too short, I would use 400 ms)
    Send, ^+{Space} ; Send Ctrl Shift Space
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Added Curly brackets around Enter!

Comment: splitting it up like this does allow me to better understand what I should be expecting at each step. ty for this solution also

Comment: I realized that I did not have Curly brackets around the Eneter command iin Send, ^+{Enter}. Please add these brackets in your code also.